# After delete item still exist in recycle view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Is that means my i didnt refresh my adapter or what?

@Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position)
    {
        FoodInfo selectedItem;

```
    if(!searchView.getQuery().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        selectedItem = newlist.get(position);
    }
    else
    {
        selectedItem = mfoodinfo.get(position);
    }

    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getFoodname();

    StorageReference imageRef = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            databaseReference.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(Recycleview.this, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Food Adapter

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mfoodinfo.size();
}

public void setFilter(List<FoodInfo> newlist) {

    mfoodinfo = new ArrayList<>();
    mfoodinfo.addAll(newlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
        MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Delete");
        MenuItem update = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Update ");


        update.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case 1:
                        mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        return true;
                    case 2:
                        mListener.UpdateFood(position);
                        return true;

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);

    void onDeleteClick(int position);

    void UpdateFood(int position);


}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

}

that is my delete method after I delete the item it still exists in my recycle view bt gone in firebase

I have to leave this page and access again then it only shows exactly the same item with firebase

Anyone help?

Comment: if u need more source code pls tell  me

Comment: Can you paste the code of FoodAdapter as well ?

Comment: @AshishKumar i already paste it

Comment: have you try adapter.notifyItemRemoved(removeIndex);

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos haven't, so in my case, i need to use position to replace removeIndex?

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos i tried, adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position), not working

Comment: thx everyone, it solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only removing it from the database , not from the adapter .

```
databaseReference.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
foodAdapter.remove(item); // this is what you need 
foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So you should have a remove method in the adapter .

**UPDATE**

This is the remove method you need on the adapter :

```
 private void remove(int position) {
    itemList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: I didn't create a method for it, I just use list.remove(position) and it works perfectly. thx anyways